# Python unittest files in subdirectory causing import failures in parent

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, python-unittest

I'm adding unit and integration tests to an existing OSS library, and the imports are failing unexpectedly when I add a subdirectory of tests.  I've boiled it down to the following:

```
.
├── driver.py
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── a.py
│   └── b.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_driver.py
```

My driver.py imports lib classes A and B:

```
$ cat driver.py
from lib import a, b

def do_it(): pass

if __name__ == '__main__': do_it()
```

and the following integration test works:

```
$ cat test/test_driver.py
import unittest, driver
from lib import a  # this import is required for some tests

class T(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_a(self): pass
```

Running:

```
$ python -m unittest discover  => Ran 1 test in 0.000s; OK
```

I'm now trying to add tests for the library files:

```
...
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── lib  <== Added dir and content
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_B.py
    └── test_driver.py
```

test_B.py contains the following:

```
import unittest
from lib import b
class T2(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_b(self): pass
```

With that added, the test_driver.py starts failing:

```
ERROR: test.test_driver (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test.test_driver
...
ImportError: cannot import name a
```

Can anyone explain why adding a subdirectory of tests impact the tests in the parent?  And what is a good way to work around this?

---

**Update:** I've got a solution, but still don't understand why. The solution was to move the integration tests to a separate subfolder:

```
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py   <= still needed for package discovery
│   ├── integration
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── test_driver.py  <= moved from top level
│   └── lib
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_B.py
```

and then all the tests ran correctly.  Can anyone explain what's going on behind-the-scenes?  Any link or doc suggestions appreciated.  Thanks, jz

Comment: Tried adding an `__init__.py` in the root folder, no effect.  Wasn't expecting any, but gave it a shot.

Comment: OK, have a workaround.  Editing the post, but still the question remains.